# How to use polymorphism with classes from different header files?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, header, polymorphism

I've got class Figure in my header "figure.h":

```
class Figure
{
    Color color;
    std::string position;
    ...
};
```

and I want to define a class King in header "king.h". So in king.h I do 
`#include "figure.h"`, and write for ex:

```
class King : public Figure
{
     char type;
     bool checkIfTypeIsValid(std::string);
     ...
};
```

But this doesn't seem to work, as King doesn't recognize Figure... What should I do? And is it smart to have different headers for different inherited classes, or just lump them together in "figure.h"? Because I'll have a Queen, Bishop, etc. figures as well, which will make quite a lot of headers and impl. files..

Comment: What do you mean by *King doesn't recognize Figure*.

Comment: This should work, you probably have an error somewhere else. Naming wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you cannot derive from an unknown, or even a partially known
class.  In order to define `King`, you must first include `Figure.h`
(supposing `King` is defined in a different file).

More generally, as to how to organize the code, there is no one
definitive answer.  Personally, in the one particular case (where the 
number of derived classes is well defined and strictly bound), I'd
probably cut corners and define all of them in `Figure.h`, but there are
very good arguments for using a separate header for each—if
nothing else, you don't have to include the headers for the individual
figures except in files where they are created.  Another solution would
be to use factory functions for the figures, and define the derived
classes in the source file which implements the factory functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need include `figure.h` at first.

```
#include<Figure.h>

class King : public Figure
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: pay attention to the casing, not everybody is on windows

Comment: The user already has done this, see "So in king.h I do #include "figure.h", and write for ex:"

Answer (score 0):

Check include path for your compiler. It would be like : -I"PATH_TO_DIR_WHERE_FIGURE_H_LOCATED", without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `king.h` contains `#include "figure.h"` or `#include <figure.h>`, as long as `figure.h` is on your include path on in the same folder as `king.h`.  If you're on Windows, the include headers can have incorrect case.  On everything else, ensure that the case is correct.  Lastly, if the definition of `Figure` is inside a namespace, you'll have to append that:

```
class King : public some_namespace::Figure
{
   //....
};
```